# Finding Recently Edited File in Bash

Tags: bash, shell

I am having some problem writing a script that gets two file names from the user and then comparing those two files of which one is edited more recently.

BASH FILE:

```
#!/bin/bash

    echo "Please Enter The File Names:"
    read filename1 filename2

    if [ $(filename1) -nt $(filename2) ]; then
        echo "$filename1 has been updated more recently"

    else
        echo " $filename2 has been updated more recently"
    fi
```

CURRENT OUTPUT:

```
Please Enter The File Names:
testFile1.c testFile2.c
./newerthanQuestion.sh: line 6: filename1: command not found
./newerthanQuestion.sh: line 6: filename2: command not found
testFile1.c has been updated more recently
```

I am not quite sure why it is showing command not found. Can someone point me in the right direction. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace this

```
 if [ $(filename1) -nt $(filename2) ]; then
```

with this:

```
 if [ $filename1 -nt $filename2 ]; then
```

`$(command)` is called command substitution, and it is used if you want to replace `$(command)` with the result of `command`

Comment: That really helps but I am still getting one more error 
`./newerthanQuestion.sh: line 6: [:missing ']'`

Comment: Please check your script, if I apply the modify explained in the answer it works.

Comment: Thank you boss, i got it